# Access Modifiers in Solidity

Tags: solidity

Say I have the following contracts

```
contract Base {
    uint256 public baseProperty;
}

contract Derived is Base {
    function getBaseProperty() public view returns (uint256) {
        return super.baseProperty;
    }
}
```

1. Is since baseProperty is public can it be modified from an external contract.

e.g  Base(address).baseProperty = 55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can do it from external contract. `public` here means you can read like this :
`Base(address).baseProperty()` Because the compiler creates a getter function for public variable so you can `get` it using the generated function `baseProperty()`. The difference between `public` and `private` is that: for `private` you need to write your own `getter` function to allow other contracts to read `baseProperty`, otherwise, no external contract can read it.

To write to baseProperty you need to write a setter function with `public` or `external` visibility, for example :

```
function writeBaseProperty(uint input) public {
  baseProperty = input;
}
```

Comment: Okay, good I just wanted to make sure that external contracts cant write to memory when a property is public.  

TBH, I don't even see why private is useful in solidity, I guess it prevents pollution of the global namespace but at the end of the day it seems like syntactic sugar